# How to programmaticaly add an UIActivityIndicatorView to a view on the bottom right corner

Tags: objective-c, uiview, positioning, ios6

I'm trying to programmatically add and position an UIActivityIndicatorView to the bottom right corner of my main view. My app can rotate.

Right now in my viewDidLoad-method I have this code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];        
UIActivityIndicatorView *iv = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        [iv startAnimating];
        int margin = 14;
        iv.frame = CGRectMake(
                                       self.view.frame.size.width - iv.frame.size.width - margin,
                                       self.view.frame.size.height - iv.frame.size.height - margin,
                                       iv.frame.size.width,
                                       iv.frame.size.height );
    iv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        [self.view addSubview:iv];
```

When the app is starting in portrait, the activity-indicator is positioned correctly. As soon as I rotate the device (or start the app in landscape) the positioning of the activityindicator is wrong.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need a flexible top margin, so that the view will slip to up or down as the height of the main view changes. Also, the parent view needs  to autoresizesSubviews set to YES (which is default YES, so you are probably ok).

```
distanceLabel.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your view controller, override the method **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** and correct the position when orientation changes.

```c
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: **Don't override this method**, it has been deprecated in iOS 6. As the documentation states: _Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i did not saw it was a io6 question.